# How do I trigger a collider on a child game object from the parent game object?

Tags: unity

I have an enemy, which has a rag doll component. It has a few child object,s and each child has its own collider. I don't want to add a script for every child, as the `OnCollisionEnter` method will be the same.

How can I do I trigger `OnCollisionEnter` with just one script, from the parent game object?

Comment: Can you provide more details on what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: I have an enemy which has ragdoll for physics
It has children for each limb(LeftArm,LeftForeArm,..etc)
All childrens have their own colliders
And there is a gameobject as a parent "Enemy"
*I want to control all collisions on one script which is working on root gameobject "Enemy"

Comment: Rigidbodies generally detect collision events for all their children colliders. Theoretically you should only have to add the handlers to the object with the rigidbodies.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to set the object up just by placing one script, and have all the logic contained in that one script, you can create a class that forwards the collision event to the parent object with gameObject.sendMessage(), or even just a reference to a public method of your parent object's script.

Instead of manually adding this class to the limbs of your ragdoll, you can use gameObject.AddComponent() to add the class dynamically.

Using gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren() will get you an array of all child objects that can get collisions, that you can then iterate over to add the forwarding script.

Comment: This answer over complicates the entire process. `OnCollisionEnter()` will naturally call based off collision with children colliders. You do not have to go to *any* additional trouble.

Comment: Maybe it does today. I don't remember about 2.5 years ago. It seems like if were so straightforward in the asker's case, they might not have needed to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you want colliders attached to child game objects to trigger your game objects `OnCollisionEnter` method, there is no reason to add *any* additional code; that is, they will *already* trigger the parent `OnCollisionEnter` method.

I have demonstrated this, below, using a basic script that prints to the debug log through a single `OnCollisionEnter` method.

---

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the parent contains the script, while the child contains the collider. Regardless, the `OnCollisionEnter` method still enters, and prints to the debug.

Comment: If i want child not get trigger from parent what should i do?